# (Access, VBA) Changing the color of a button on a Form based on CheckBox values from a Table located on the Forms's Record Source

Tags: vba, ms-access, path-finding

I am working on creating a database for the Aquaculture sector. In a Form I have placed buttons for each "pool" that exists on place:
[image: Form interface]
So you get an idea, the buttons have following code that forwards to another Form with specific information about given pool:

```
Private Sub cmd2_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmd2_Click_Err
    codBaseNum = "AT 1/2"

DoCmd.OpenForm "InfoBotonTanque", acNormal, "", "[Base-Número]=""AT 1/2""", , acLast

cmd2_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmd2_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmd2_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Based on two different checkboxes on a Table with information about individual pools, I want the buttons to change color. Here the data from the Table:

[image]

Checkbox names: [Reserva] and [Condicion?]. [Base-Número] is the pools ID. All three values are in the Form's RecordSource:

[image]

EDIT:
Managed to acomplish what I wanted: buttons change color based on CheckBox values! The following code is not ellegant, for I have to type the same with small changes for each button and there are about 150 of them, but it works... The used code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()    
If DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = True And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = False Then
    Me.cmd2.BackColor = RGB(255, 215, 0)
ElseIf DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = False And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = True Then
    Me.cmd2.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = False And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/2'") = False Then
    Me.cmd2.BackColor = RGB(51, 171, 249)
Else
    Me.cmd2.BackColor = RGB(120, 120, 120)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't reference a table in VBA like that. If Tanques is not in form RecordSource, either include it or use DLookup(). Edit question to show complete error message. Also show data as text tables.

Comment: Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention, nor reserved words as names.

Comment: An alternative is to use textboxes formatted to look like buttons and use Conditional Formatting instead of VBA.

Comment: I have added the information June7 suggested.@June7, could you please refer me to a post where  the textboxes are used as buttons?

Comment: An image of table design is not data. It is not a text table. How are buttons supposed to be connected to data? No, I can't - maybe you will have better luck with Google search. Just have to play with textbox formatting. Textbox also has a Click event. What do you mean by "List"?

Comment: @june7. Have posted how the buttons are connected to the data, they are just gateways. Changed the code a bit. Does not promt an error now. I ment to write Table, not List mb.

Comment: This is more complicated by using buttons. Would have to loop through records and set color of a corresponding button. That means extracting sequence number from Base value and buttons would have to be named to correspond. Using a textbox bound to Base field allows Conditional Formatting rules to set BackColor dependent on values of Reserva and Condicion. Code should always be text, not image. Also preferable for data to be text and not image.

Comment: Correction, extract from Base-Numero for buttons and bind to Base-Numero for textbox. Textbox formatted to look like button and/or a hyperlink.

Comment: @june7 Found a way to do it as I wanted. Updated the post with the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Essentially what I suggested in my first comment. There is a way to do this so don't have to repeat code 150 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to repeat code 150 times, use a loop that constructs command button name as well as [Base-Número] parameter with a variable. Consider:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 to 150
    If DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = True _
               And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = False Then
        Me("cmd" & x ).BackColor = RGB(255, 215, 0)
    ElseIf DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = False _
               And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = True Then
        Me("cmd" & x).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf DLookup("[Reserva]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = False _
               And DLookup("[Condicion?]", "Tanques", "[Base-Número] = 'AT 1/" & x & "'") = False Then
        Me("cmd" & x).BackColor = RGB(51, 171, 249)
    Else
        Me("cmd" & x).BackColor = RGB(120, 120, 120)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```