# Conditional visibility on MS Access Form - how to write in VBA or Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-statements, visibility

I have some very (**very**) basic MS Access knowledge. I'm trying to expand a bit into either VBA or macros as I'd like to put in some conditional visibility for my form. Basically, I have a checkbox. If it's checked, I want three or four more fields to pop up. Someone was able to point me to a basic VBA formula of if (this checkbox) = true then, (fieldx).visible = true, else, (fieldx).visibility = false, end if.

But I'm so new to this that I need more help and explanation. I tried putting it in but couldn't get it to work (no error message, just nothing changed at all).

Specific questions:

-Does this formula seem right?

-If I want multiple fields to be visible, can I combine them into one formula or should I create a new "if" statement for all?

-Where do I enter this code? I'm running the Office 365 version. For all I know, I'm not even putting it in the right place.

-How do I determine the field names to replace the (this checkbox) and (fieldx) in the formula? I tried entering the name I title the fields as, but with the spaces in the name I got an error message, and without the spaces nothing happened. Is there a specific naming convention to turn the field names into formula-appropriate titles? Is the name listed somewhere?

-Once I get the formula entered, is there something I have to do to get it to run/take effect? I tried saving, closing and reopening with no changes.

-Is this the best way to go about this?

If there's anything else you think I should know, I would love to hear it - but please keep in mind I'm **very** new to this so if you could keep it at "dummy" or ELI5 levels of explanation, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: If that is your actual code, then no it is not right - the idea is right but not the code - it shouldn't even compile. Code has to be in some event such as form Current or checkbox AfterUpdate or both. If form is in Continuous or Datasheet, this will not work as you want. Programmatically setting control property affects ALL instances of control so all records will show the same result. Alternatively, can use textbox and combobox Conditional Formatting to dynamically enable/disable by record, still visible but cannot enter control.

Comment: You use names of controls and if controls have same name as field then yes use field name. I always name controls different from fields. So textbox for Quantity field would be named tbxQty. Don't use spaces in naming convention. Nor punctuation/special characters nor reserved words; if you do then enclose in brackets in code `[Date Entered]`. You will see query builder automatically adds brackets but in VBA you have to consciously do it.

Comment: One If statement can set visibility of all controls. If there are a lot of controls, code can be consolidated with variables, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138295/access-vba-changing-the-color-of-a-button-on-a-form-based-on-checkbox-values/66249858#66249858

Answer (score 2):

after creating a form with 4 textboxes and a checkbox put the form in design mode (lower right corner has design mode selected,   select a textbox and hit property sheet on the ribbon (or f4).
On the property sheet note the visible property.  set the visible property to false.   Now the textbox will be invisible when the form starts.

[image]

Tip you can select all the textboxes at the same time and set their properties all at once.

Every control on the form and even the various parts of the form have properties you can set and play with.  For instance you can give any name you want to any control.  On the property sheet go to the other tab and set the name property.

[image]

Tip: choose a name you you will remember without having to look it up and describes the controls function.
Next select the checkbox (not the checkbox's label).  On the property sheet go to the event tab and select the on click event.  hit the ellipsis and choose code builder.  Access is Event Driven.  We want the textboxes to appear when the checkbox is selected so we put that code in the checkbox click event.

[image]

after choosing code builder we get the code window where we can browse among all the events for all our forms.  for now all you should see is something like:

```
Private Sub mycheckbox_Click()

End Sub
```

So insert some code to handle the checkboxes like:

```
Private Sub mycheckbox_Click()
If mycheckbox = True Then
txtbox1.Visible = True
txtbox2.Visible = True
txtbox3.Visible = True
txtbox4.Visible = True
Else
txtbox1.Visible = False
txtbox2.Visible = False
txtbox3.Visible = False
txtbox4.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

now when the checkbox is not checked no textboxes are visible.
[image]

but when the checkbox is checked they appear

[image]

Comment: Or simply `txtbox1.Visible = mycheckbox.Value`.